# need to join arrays in to single one

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter-3

how can we join this two arrays into one array

for this, I had done my code like this and got the output as shown below

```
$groups_array = array_map('trim',explode(',', $tt));
```

`$tt` looks like this `string(5) "11:00" string(5) "10:00"`

```
array(1) { [0]=> string(5) "11:00" } array(1) { [0]=> string(5) "10:00" }
```

need desired output to look like

```
array(1) { [0]=> string(5) "11:00",[1]=> string(5) "10:00" }
```

My code is here please have a look

```
<?php $time_booked=$this->Hospital_model->get_already_booked_time($d,$timeslot->doctor_id);

   foreach($time_booked as $index1=> $t) {

    $tt=$t->time;
    $groups_array = array_merge(array_map('trim',explode(',', $ttt)));


} ?>
```

my `var_dump($time_booked)` looks like this

```
array(2) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#40 (1) { ["time"]=> string(5) "11:00" } [1]=> object(stdClass)#41 (1) { ["time"]=> string(5) "10:00" } }
```

Comment: Are `$tt` value changed every-time (as you posted two different value for it)? Is your code running inside some kind of loop?

Comment: @AlivetoDie yes my code is running inside a loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about [array_merge()](http://php.net/manual/de/function.array-merge.php) with [array_map()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php)

```
$groups_array = array_merge(array_map('trim',explode(',', $tt)));
```

Output:-https://eval.in/1012484

***By looking your edit in your question no need to do any extra stuff***, just create an array and add values to it

```
<?php 
  $groups_array = []; //create array
  $time_booked=$this->Hospital_model->get_already_booked_time($d,$timeslot->doctor_id);

  foreach($time_booked as $index1=> $t) {
     $groups_array[] =$t->time; //add values to array
  }
  var_dump($groups_array);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

What about array_merge ? That should give you the result.

http://php.net/manual/de/function.array-merge.php

EDIT:

```
$tt = ['11:00'];
$tt2 = ['10:00'];

$result = array_merge($tt,$tt2);

var_dump($result);
```

Result is

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(5) "11:00"
  [1]=>
  string(5) "10:00"
}
```

Is that not what you meant ?

Comment: even array_merge will produce the same result

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have two array which look like

```
$array1 = array(0 => "10:00 am");
$array2 = array(0 => "11:00 am");
```

and you want to join and want output like: Array ( [0] => 10:00 am [1] => 11:00 am )

then you can use array_merge option

```
$array3 = array_merge($array1, $array2);
```

If you print `print_r($array3);`
output will be

```
Array ( [0] => 10:00 am [1] => 11:00 am )
```